# How is google giving every page a rank out of 10?

Tags: php, networking, seo, pagerank

according to wikipedia:[PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)

> A probability is expressed as a
>   numeric value between 0 and 1. A 0.5
>   probability is commonly expressed as a
>   "50% chance" of something happening.
>   Hence, a PageRank of 0.5 means there
>   is a 50% chance that a person clicking
>   on a random link will be directed to
>   the document with the 0.5 PageRank.

they are saying that the sum of all the pageranks in any network should be equal 1

my question is,

so how is google giving every page a rank out of 10?!

I am asking this question because I have calculated the pagerank for my small local network

but I am ending with a small pagerank numbers like 0.0286358921402

how can I change them to be in percent % ,or out of 10?

Thanks

Comment: http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/google-fact-behind-google-page-rank-algorithm/  Got some idea from here

Answer (score 1):

Multiply it by 100. That converts decimal (0.02) to percent (2.0%).

Comment: To add to that, I think Google then probably rounds.  So, in your case, you have a Page Rank of 0.0286, they multiply by 100 to get 2.86% and then round, 3%.

Comment: @Jason: True, or they truncate (eg., 2.86 becomes 2%).

Answer (score 1):

From the same [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) link:

> The PageRank is derived from a
>   theoretical probability value on a
>   logarithmic scale like the Richter Scale

Here is another interesting [article](http://pr.efactory.de/e-pagerank-algorithm.shtml)

By the way, i am curious: how exactly did you calculate your pagerank? it's not exactly a simple algorithm...

Comment: The actual question was "how can I change 0.0286358921402 to a percentage".

Comment: @Ken White: and to quote the OP: "how is google giving every page a rank out of 10?!"

Comment: @jcinacio: Read again, particularly the last line of the OP. Then ask yourself, "Is the subject the question, or is the question the question?"

Comment: i have read it: "my question is,

so how is google giving every page a rank out of 10?!"

Answer (score 0):

If you wind up getting different results than Google does, do note from the Wikipedia article (emphases mine):

> Google assigns a numeric weighting from 0-10 for each webpage on the Internet; this PageRank denotes a site’s importance in the eyes of Google. The PageRank is derived from a theoretical probability value on a logarithmic scale like the Richter Scale. The PageRank of a particular page is **roughly** based upon the quantity of inbound links as well as the PageRank of the pages providing the links. It is known that other factors, e.g. relevance of search words on the page and actual visits to the page reported by the Google toolbar also influence the PageRank. In order to prevent manipulation, spoofing and Spamdexing, **Google provides no specific details about how other factors influence PageRank**.

Answer (score -1):

what about taking a look at this :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

Comment: I imagine he has, seeing as he quoted that same link in his question.